# Set Service to be called from button in Android

Tags: java, android, service

I have these buttons that work:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonPlay) {
        buttonStopPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stopbutton);
        buttonPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonpressed);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Buffering...";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 200);
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) toast.getView();
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) group.getChildAt(0);
        messageTextView.setTextSize(40);
        toast.show();
        startPlaying();
    } else if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonStopPlay) {
        buttonPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
        buttonStopPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stopbuttonpressed);
        stopPlaying();
    }
}
```

I want to set a simple service to keep `startPlaying();` when app is minimized, so I did this:

```
    public class BgMusicService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        startPlaying();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonPlay) {
        buttonStopPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stopbutton);
        buttonPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonpressed);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Buffering...";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 200);
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) toast.getView();
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) group.getChildAt(0);
        messageTextView.setTextSize(40);
        toast.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BgMusicService.class);
        startService(intent);
    } else if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonStopPlay) {
        buttonPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
        buttonStopPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stopbuttonpressed);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BgMusicService.class);
        stopService(intent);
        stopPlaying();
    }
}
```

However, service is not working. Is there something I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onStartCommand()` into your service and call your `startPlaying()` method in there. Also you need to use a long background operation with `Service`, not an `IntentService`. `IntentSerice` is beeing kiled after operation is ended.

Comment: In alte cuvinte ar trebui sa folosesc Service, nu IntentService?

Comment: Da, deoarece un serviciu executa o operatie de lunga durata si poate continua chiar daca s-a terminat, pe când un intent service se ucide atunci când termina. Cred ca nu ar fi trebuit sa-ti raspund in romana, ci in engleza.

Comment: Did you added the service declaration into Manifest?

Comment: Added `<service android:name=".Homepage$BgMusicService" />` but now app crashes when I hit the `buttonPlay`

Comment: Use `.` instead `$` <service android:name=".Homepage.BgMusicService" />

Comment: "When you reference to an inner class in a manifest file, you must use `$` instead of `.`"

Comment: Y know, use dot, not dollar sign.

Comment: Should I set the Service on a separate .java file, rather than the main java file?

Comment: You receive that warning because packages must start with lowercase, only classes must start with uppercase because package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.

Comment: Yes, you should. Is better to clean your code and make it modular.

Comment: I can't because then I can't import `startPlaying();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144397/discussion-between-florescu-george-ctlin-and-xmaster-official).